# How to proxy a HTTP video stream to any amount of clients through a Spring Webserver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, video, video-streaming

Provided that I have a video HTTP stream broadcasted on a server that is on the same network as my Spring Webserver is, for instance in some url such as:

> http://localhost:9090/httpstream

How can I proxy this video stream to any amount of clients, using Spring?
The following example demonstrates the wanted flow:

1. Spring webserver can be found at http://localhost:9091/spring
2. A client wants to access a video stream, so he connects his video-stream-player to http://localhost:9091/spring (the spring webserver)
3. The Spring WebServer should redirect the stream found on http://localhost:9090/httpstream to the client, with the latter never knowing that he accessed the httpstream host. The connection is made by Spring, not by the client

This is needed because the HTTPStream is an unsecured and not authenticated host, and I wanted to wrap it around a `Spring Webserver`, so that I could use some form of Security, such as a `Basic Auth`.

---

I tried requesting some form of mapping, but I couldn't find what kind of object to return, nor how to make the connection, but the expected behaviour should be something like this:

```
@Controller
public class HttpStreamProxyController {

    @RequestMapping("/spring") {
    public /*Stream Object?*/ getSecuredHttpStream() {
       if (clientIsSecured) {
       //... Security information

       return   //What should be returned?
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I really think you are over engineering this, and it can be solved by using SSL termination at your networks off-loader. Client requests would come in to your network as "HTTPS", have the certificate validation happen in the off-loader, and then get forwarded to your service. If you require authentication, like logging in, basic auth, or some flavor of OAuth, all of that can still be handled by the source service. However, I get that sometimes you "just gotta do it", so if you are interested I could putting together an example using Zuul proxy.

Comment: I'm interested in the authentication part. It can't be done by the source service, as it only provides a broadcasted HTTP stream from an IP Camera. I want to collect that http stream and redstribute it, and for that I'd like to use Spring Boot

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are looking for. I may not get to it before Monday though.

Comment: No problem. I really want to understand this concept. Proxying a stream through java. Proxying a Rest response is easier, through a RestTemplate, for example

Comment: Are you planning to write your own stream receiver on the client side for this or is it required to work with standard HTML5 and cross browser/cross platform?

Comment: I'm likely going to write my own stream receiver. It would be best if it would work with standard HTML5

Comment: I have updated my answer with perhaps what spring proxy with StreamingResponseBody could look like. It works fine with HTML5. See if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of source you are using for generating your video stream (live camera or a video file or youtube video or ..)

You can probably use StreamingResponseBody (requires Spring 4.2+). Refer following links

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/streaming-response-body/

http://shazsterblog.blogspot.in/2016/02/asynchronous-streaming-request.html

Try this -

```
    @GetMapping("/stream1")
        @ResponseBody
        public StreamingResponseBody getVidoeStream1(@RequestParam String any) throws IOException {
            /* do security check before connecting to stream hosting server */ 
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange( "http://localhost:8080/stream", HttpMethod.GET, null, Resource.class );
            InputStream st = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();
            return (os) -> {
                readAndWrite(st, os);
            };


    }

private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(data)) > 0) {
            os.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
    }
```

It should work. You can write your own implementation of readAndWrite() depending on your requirements.

So, your spring proxy controller could be something like this...

```
@Controller
public class HttpStreamProxyController {

    @RequestMapping("/spring") 
    @ResponseBody
    public StreamingResponseBody  getSecuredHttpStream() {
       if (clientIsSecured) {
       //... Security information

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // get video stream by connecting to stream hosting server  like this
            ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange( "https://ur-to-stream", HttpMethod.GET, null, Resource.class );
            InputStream st = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();
    // Or if there is any other preferred way of getting the video stream use that. The idea is to get the video input stream    

    // now return a StreamingResponseBody  object created by following lambda 
            return (os) -> {
                readAndWrite(st, os);
            };

       } else {
          return null;
       }

   }
}
```

The StreamingResponseBody returned by your rest endpoint will work fine with HTML5, which could be something like ..

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/spring" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
```

Comment: This is likely correct, @vsoni, I'll give it a test and accept this as the answer.

Comment: when trying restTemplate.exchange(..) the request hangs, and never go to the next line. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Are you getting any exception on the server? ... OR are you able to get data stream when you access your url from browser directly? I mean the url that you are trying to access thru restTemplate.exchange

Comment: No errors, and the request never complete. after a while I get a 503 error on the source (accessing via VLC). I solved it using RestTemplate `execute` method, but am still studying the issue

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this same problem for days, attempting to migrate my node app to Spring/React. I'm using a raspberry pi running Motion, which acts as a remote stream server that I was previously able to use the node module `mjpeg-proxy` to easily proxy the way OP wishes. This thread was the most useful set of examples in my search to do this in Java, however none of the examples quite worked for me. I'm hoping my controller class and component will help others attempting the same.

Please take note of `response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=BoundaryString");` as the `boundary=BoundaryString` portion was the last critical piece. I opened the chrome debugger while connecting directly to the stream and this was in the response headers -- when I copied it, suddenly everything worked!

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.net.URI;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/video")
public class VideoController {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VideoController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/oculus")
    public void oculus(HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("Calling /video/oculus...");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.execute(
                URI.create("http://oculus:8081"),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                (ClientHttpRequest request) -> {},
                responseExtractor -> {
                    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=BoundaryString");
                    IOUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
                    return null;
                }
        );
    }

    @RequestMapping("/door")
    public void door(HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("Calling /video/door...");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.execute(
                URI.create("http://vox:9002"),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                clientHttpRequest -> {
                    clientHttpRequest.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic blahblahBase64encodedUserAndPass=");
                },
                responseExtractor -> {
                    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=BoundaryString");
                    IOUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
                    return null;
                }
        );
    }

}
```

I have included examples for using Motion's basic auth, as well as an unprotected stream.

Both streams are then available on my app using the following bit of react js

````
class Video extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Content">
                <p>
                    <img className="stream" src="/video/oculus"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <img className="stream" src="/video/door"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Video;```
````

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do video streaming in a Spring Boot application (I used a different source, however — a USB camera):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> stream() {
    StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream -> {
        while (streaming.get()) {
            final var raw = streamImage.get();
            final var jpeg = convert(byte2Buffered(raw.getImageData(), raw.getImageWidth(), raw.getImageHeight()));
            outputStream.write(jpeg);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    };
    final var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Max-Age", "0");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(stream);
}
```

This way you'll get a stream on URL endpoint, which you can embed into a web page using `img` HTML tag.

Comment: Could you provide more details of your solution. It's not clear origin of streaming.get() and streamImage.get(). I'm trying to achieve your approach, but struggling with returning of sequence of jpeg images from camera as live stream .

Comment: @Zhandos
`streaming.get()` is a variable of  `AtomicBoolean` type which indicates whether there is data available in the stream. `streamImage.get();` is a variable of class `AtomicReference<V> implements java.io.Serializable` which points to the array of the images. This class with the array of images is provided by the SDK which comes with the device. I suggest checking whether your device can provide something similar or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to kurento media server. http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2many.html. It works with `WEB-RTC` and works well for my current project.

as they state:

> You can use whatever Java server side technology you prefer to build
>   web applications with Kurento. For example, a pure Java EE
>   application, SIP Servlets, Play, Vertex, etc. We chose Spring Boot for
>   convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with restTemplate exchange didn't work properly for video streams (mp4 in my case), cause request hangs on and client does not recieve any data. Take a look at execute method. Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

@GetMapping("/video")    
public void process(HttpServletResponse response) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.execute(            
        URI.create("https://some-url"),            
        HttpMethod.GET,            
        (ClientHttpRequest request) -> {},            
        responseExtractor -> {                
            response.setContentType("video/mp4");                
            IOUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());                
            return null;            
        }
    );    
}
```